# javascript number formatting on keyup event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to format number in an input field on keyup event but I kept getting a warning on the console of my browser
*The specified value "5,545" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.* 
and the value I have entered in the input field cleans up. Please what can be done to solve the problem?
 Below is the jquery code snippet that handles the number formatting:

```
$('input[type="number"]').keyup(function(event) {
        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            return value
            .replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')  
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
        });
    });
```

Error or warning I get in the browser console is:
[image]

 and the value in my input field cleans up after displaying this warning. Please what is wrong and what can be done?

Comment: I think you should give the code rather than an image of it.

Comment: You're trying to set a number `<input>` to a value that's not a valid number.

Comment: @Pointy thanks. I know the problem now and have solved it

Answer (score 2):

What causes the error is the `,` since `5,289` try changing the `,` to a `.`

EX:
`'5,289' => '5.289'`

Comment: but I want the numbers to be formatted with both commas after three digits and 2 decimal places of value. Please how do I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to format, it means you want a string to be displayed to the user, not a number, so you should not use an `<input type="number" />` to do so. Does that make sense to you (I am not sure I am saying this right)?