# $('#input5').val(total) return input:157 The specified value "1.234.567" cannot be parsed, or is out of range?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Question similar with this problem [stackoverflow.com/questions/61961905/javascript-number-formatting-on-keyup-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961905/javascript-number-formatting-on-keyup-event), but I can,t find the answer there.

My Code was like this :

```
$('#input2').change(function(){
    var format = new Number('1234567').toLocaleString("id-ID");
    $('#input4').val(format);
}
```

while my html was like this :

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="input2" name="jumlah">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="input4" name="total" disabled>
```

And the result was :

```
The specified value "1.234.567" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
```

What can i do now ?

Comment: Don't use input type number. Use `type=text` instead.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek why like this ? Is this type=number so poor ?

Comment: Do you simply want the number to be inserted into the input field?

Comment: @SuryaTanamas check out my answer for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.234.567` is not a valid number (from JavaScript perspective) and therefore, it can't be set as a value of input `type=number`. The problem is with parsing such a number: should it be interpreted as `1 234 567`, `1.234567` or `1234.567` etc?

In order to use such a format, you need to change your input type to `text` and everything should work fine. But keep in mind that doing so will make the value a text, so in order to make it a number you would need to manually convert it.

Comment: Thx for explanation sir. I already get the problem here. Again thanks for helping me and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `#input4` to `text`, because the formatted one is not a valid number.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input2').change(function() {
    var format = new Number('1234567').toLocaleString("id-ID");
    $('#input4').val(format);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="input2" name="jumlah">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input4" name="total" disabled>
```